# Stability of the dynamic system

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-theory, delay-differential-equations, steady-state

I have a function ${\dot{\varphi } = \gamma - F(\varphi )}$ (where $\varphi$ - is 2${\pi }$-periodic function) and graph of function $F(\varphi)$. So it's needed to research this graph (to find the equilibrium states and find out if they are stable, unstable, or semi-stable, build phase portraits and so on),to build a phase portrait and to calculate this integral: $\int \frac{d\varphi }{\gamma -F(\varphi ))}=\int dt$ to get $\varphi (t)$.

```
                 ^
                 |
                 |1   ______
                 |   /|     \
                 |  / |      \
                 | /  |       \
__-π_______-a____|/___|________\π____>
   \        |   /|0    a
    \       |  / |
     \      | /  |
      \     |/   |
       ¯¯¯¯¯¯    |-1
```

As I see, a segment ${[a, \pi -a]}$ is the segment of equilibrium states and any straight line $y = k$, where k ${\in (0,1)}$ would have 2 e.s. Also if $\gamma=1$ there would be only one e.s. Is it right?
How can I find out what they are? And could you please help me to build the phase portrait?

Comment: Is $\varphi$ scalar?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen it's not stated, but I think it is so

Comment: If $|\gamma|>$ then there is no equilibrium. If $|\gamma| = 1$ then you do not have isolated equilibriums, but you have invariant (equilibrium) sets. And if $|\gamma|<1$ then  (on the interval $[-\pi, \ \pi]$ you have two equilibrium points. Suppose that $\gamma>0$, then you have one stable equilibrium point $a\gamma$ and on unstable $\pi - a\gamma$.

Comment: @Arastas thank you! may I ask you one more question? How can I know what are these equilibriums are? I mean if they are saddle, proper node, focus, centre. And how to calculate φ(t)? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: As far as I see, your $\phi$ is scalar. Then your equilibrium can be only a node. No saddle/focus/center exists for first-order systems. To find the solution $\phi$ try to consider it by intervals. On each interval, the system is a standard text-book example.